# An easy Ques from a beginner of Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

I got the following error message

> **NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object   from (irb):2    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in`'**

if my code was as follows:

```
[1,2,3].each{|x| a=x}
puts x
```

However, if I put one sentence at the beginning of the script, everything was OK.

```
a=nil
```

Would anyone tell me why 'a=nil' is necessary?
Thanks!

Comment: Your error message is incorrect. The code you show should be complaining about `x` not about `a`.

Comment: Please rename your question so it explains what you are asking for.

Comment: Your problem statement is in error. You mean `puts a`, not `puts x`?

Comment: Please try to come up with titles to your question that are more indicative of the question. "An easy Ques from a beginner of Ruby" tells us nothing about your question, nor will it tell anything to anyone who is searching for an answer to the same thing you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[1,2,3].each{|x| a = x} 
puts a
```

Here you have created `a` inside the block. So `a` is only accessible inside the block. Outside world don't know who is `a`. `a` is lexically scoped to block. Thus when, you are trying to use `a` before introducing it to the outside scope of the block, *MRI* complaining about `a`. If you try to access `x` also, you will be having the same complains from *MRI*.

```
[1].each do |x|
  a = x 
  local_variables # => [:x, :a]
end

local_variables # => []
```

---

```
a = nil
[1,2,3].each{|x| a = x} 
puts a
```

Now you created `a` outside the block, which is top level. Now `#each` method takes a block `{ |..| ... }`. Blocks are *closure* in Ruby, i.e.  it has access to the outside variables, which are created before the block is defined. Inside the block, you can access the `a`, which you defined outside and update it also. Now when bock will be ended its execution, you can see the last updated value of `a`. *But if you try to access `x`, you will get the same *error/complains* from *MRI* as you got above.* - The reason being, `x` lexically scoped to the block, where you have created it firs time, outer scope, ie, outside the block, it has no existence.

```
a = nil
[1].each do |x|
  a = x
  local_variables # => [:x, :a]
end

local_variables # => [:a]
```

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that when variable a is declared already, it becomes recognizable outside the block and its value will be set according to its value inside the block?

Comment: Ruby Parser and IRB do not behave 100% identical - keep this in mind. The only real way to find out the behaviour is to i.e. store the content of the code directly in a .rb file and run that.

Comment: @mbratch Is it clear now, or i am missing something ?

Comment: The problem was that the OP's question is actually incorrectly stated. It says `puts x` but I think the OP intended `puts a`.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? Is there any way to make the variable a defined inside the block inaccessible from outside? That is to say, the value of variable a will still be 'nil'?

Comment: @user3476791 Yes.Just do `a = nil
[1,2,3].each{|x;a| a = x} 
puts a`.. Now `a` is `nil` outside the block.